# I'm having this problem: undefined method `each' for #<User:0xa8dc8b8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
19: <strong>URL</strong> <%= link_to user_path(@user),(@user)%><br />
20: 
21: <strong>Thoughts</strong> <%= @user.thoughts.count %>
22: <% @user.each do |user| %>
23: <li>
24:   <% if Friendship.are_friends(current_user, user) %>
25:     (you are friends)
```

It's throwing the error at line 22. I don't understand why. I'm simply just trying to do the loop for each friend.

EDIT:1

I'm actually trying to send a friendship request through a link in my social networks sidebar. Here is the code it missed out:

```
     <% @user.friendship.each do |user| %>
          <li>
<% if Friendship.are_friends(current_user, user) %>
  (you are friends)
<% elsif current_user != user %>
  (<%= link_to "request friendship", :controller => :friendship, :action => :req, :id => user.name %>)
                <% end %>
                </li>
<% end %>

<h2>Your Friends</h2>
<ol>
<% @user.each do |friendship| %>
  <li><%= friendship.friend.name %>, <%= friendship.status %></li>
<% end %>
</ol>
```

I've tried adding user.friendship and it does render the page but there is no link to add friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you probably need to pluralise 'friendship'.  If a user has_many :friendships, then your code should be @user.friendships.each

Secondly, @user.friendships.each will return Friendships, not Users.  How are your models set up?  Assuming you have a User model, and a Friendship model.  The friendship model should look something like this:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attributes should be :person_id, friend_id
  belongs_to :person, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
end
```

And the user model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships, :foreign_key => "person_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
end
```

In which case, you would want to use @user.friends.each instead of @user.friendships.each.  The first will loop through an array of Users, the second will loop through Friendships.

Comment: Hey thanks. I was following this guide: http://rails.francik.name/tutorial/chapter/11 
He seemed to use :Friendship

I've changed it to a twitter style model now, where theres no need for confirmation, and it works. Thanks for your help tho

Answer (score 4):

`@user` is a single record (one user) -- you use `.each` to loop through an array of records, not a single record.

Maybe you meant something like `@user.friends.each do |user|`?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the very fast response. What I intend to do though is have a link to send the request for a friendship. Sorry the original post didn't show that bit:

Comment: Hey, sorry not sure how to navigate Stack Overflow yet, and made a bit of a mess up. Please see my original post for edit